# Getting the output stream of "cmd.exe" in Java

Tags: java

I wanted to create something like a remote control for the command line in Windows.

For this I am using a scanner, but...

The problem is, when I read the whole line with nextLine() from the stream, the prompt will be missing (becouse is is printed, but not in a line) - and when I read the next word with next(), the line break is missing and you will lose the overview. However, some information is even missing.

```
package com;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StdinCmd extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        try {
            execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void execute() throws IOException {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(MainClient.getProcess().getInputStream()); // <- getting the stream
        StdoutSocket stdoutSocket = new StdoutSocket();
        while (true) {
            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                stdoutSocket.executeNext(reader.next()); // <- send it to the socket (the controller). This is what will be displayed at the end.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I attached a screenshot of how it should look like, and how it looks at the end:

http://www.mediafire.com/?jma31ezg8ansfal

I hope you can help me and I gave you enough information!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirecting Input/Output/Error Streams of a CMD.exe Process Completely with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301270/redirecting-input-output-error-streams-of-a-cmd-exe-process-completely-with-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `Scanner` or `BufferedReader`, but instead read directly from the `InputStream`...

```
InputStream is = null;
try {
    is = MainClient.getProcess().getInputStream();
    int in = -1;
    while ((in = is.read()) != -1) {
        System.out.print(((char)in));
    }
} catch (IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        is.close();
    } catch (Exception exp) {
    }
}
```

Comment: **EDIT**  When I type >ftp and enter the password of my ftp server, client and server will both crash, becouse it is not redirected correctly to the stream with password fields as it seams. Any idea?

Comment: This is going to be a problem when ruining remote applications of this nature, as the stdin/stdout no longer match. As to a solute I've never seen anyone come up with one, but I've not looked that hard...

Answer (score 1):

Personally I really don't like scanner so much. If you want to read input line's from a user and send it through a socket.. Who not then just use a BufferedReader with System.in?
Read a line and send it through the socket.

```
BufferedReader br = new BUfferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line = null;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    OutSocket.send(line); // or how you send it..
}
```

~Foorack

Comment: Almost, but I tried something like this before and remember it was not working without bugs. But thanks anyway!